# How to remove element from gsettings array in script?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, dconf, gsettings

Array in dbus/gsettings has a format `[element1, element2, element3, ...]`.

`Gsettings`' interface allows only replacing existing array with another, so for instance, adding another item element can be achieved as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
gsettings get ${schema} ${key} | grep -q \"${value}\" >/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
   gsettings set ${schema} ${key} \"`gsettings get ${schema} ${key} | sed s/.$//`, ${value}]\"
fi
```

Can anyone help me with a script, that checks whether at least one element exists that matches the regex, and if it does, it parses the gsettings`array string, and removes all matching elements (and puts it back with`gsettings set`, but that is trivial).

I tried to find such tool, but I failed to find one. I cannot believe, that nobody yet had a need for such tool...

---

The question complements [How to add element to the gsettings array at the specific location (given by index)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461654/how-to-add-element-to-the-gsettings-array-at-the-specific-location-given-by-ind/461707)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using bash for this task should be possible but I prefer doing complex array manipulations with a Python3 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse
import subprocess
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("schema", help="gsettings shema", metavar="SCHEMA")
parser.add_argument("key", help="gsettings key", metavar="KEY")
parser.add_argument("values",
                    help="gsettings value(s) to remove from the KEY array",
                    metavar="VALUE", nargs='*')
args = parser.parse_args()

array = eval(subprocess.check_output(["gsettings", "get", args.schema, args.key]))
for v in args.values:
    try:
        value = eval(v)
    except:
        value = v
    try:
        array.remove(value)
    except ValueError:
        print("Warning: {} not in {} {}".format(value, args.schema, args.key), file=sys.stderr)
subprocess.call(["gsettings", "set", args.schema, args.key, str(array)])
```

This script allow multiple values to be removed at the same time from the schema/key  passed to the script.

Comment: Works flawlessly if the element is actually present in the list (easy to check with `gsettings get ${schema} ${key} | grep -q "${value}"` )

Comment: You're right, I didn't check if targeted values were actually present in the array. I'll update my answer

Comment: Done, I now print a warning if one of the values is not in the array

Comment: Another problem, this one I cannot fix: `./remove.py org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources "('xkb', 'us')"` doesn't finds the entry. I guess it has something to do with `'` quotes or spaces in the argument.

Comment: I've updated my answer to handle this case where basically I first need to "eval" such patterns to find a match in the gsettings array

Comment: It's better to use Pythonic API instead of shell parsing output:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/313338/gnome3-how-do-i-remove-favorites-from-dash-via-terminal